# How do I display all of the images from my Firebase Storage in React Native without needing image names?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

Hello i am trying to figure out how to display all of the images in a folder i have in Firebase Storage called "VerifiedPhotos". I don't want to reference them by image name like I did below because I have multiple images. How do I grab all the list of image URLS and display them to my screen in React Native? Please help I have spent all week looking up how to use listAll() and I also am not sure how to display the multiple images in the return statement. Please help.

```
  const Photos = () => {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
      firebase.storage()
        .ref('VerifiedPhotos/' + '3.png') //name in storage in firebase console
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          setImageUrl(url);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('Errors while downloading => ', e));
    }, []);
  
  return (
      <Image style={{height: 200, width: 200}} source={{uri: imageUrl}} />
  );
}

export default Photos;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation said about `.listAll()` [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#listall), you need to iterate through results :

```
const Photos = () => {
  const [imageTab, setImageTab] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.storage()
      .ref('VerifiedPhotos/')
      .listAll()
      .then(function(result) {
          result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
              imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                  imageTab.push(url);
                  setImageTab(imageTab);
              }).catch(function(error) {
                  // Handle any errors
              });
          });
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log('Errors while downloading => ', e));
  }, []);

  return (<View>
    {imageTab.map(i => (<Image style={{height: 200, width: 200}} source={{uri: i}} />))}
  </View>);
}

export default Photos;
```

Let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Edited : I fixed it by separate push `setImageTab(imageTab);` from set state

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. So I tried this code and it's only working if i refresh the code. If i press on the button that loads this code it just shows a blank screen (doesn't pull from firebase until i do control s on the code). Can you please help me with this? Also, how can I do it so if i add new pictures in the folder in firebase it'll auto pull those changes on my mobile screen? Thank you.

Comment: never mind, I actually used your return method along with this answer's (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64708353/how-to-display-all-the-images-from-firebase-storage-in-react?rq=1) useEffect() method and now it's pulling the images. but it isn't auto pulling changes (like if I delete an image or place a new image) on the screen unless I refresh the code. do you know how I can solve this? or i might post it as another q so people can see the full code

Comment: Happy to help!  yep post another question please